# How to use/load .rc file for multiligual application?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I am working on a multilingual application using VC++, MFC in visual studio. I am having separate .rc file for each language.
say

```
English.rc   //having string table for English language
French.rc    //having string table for French language
German.rc     //having string table for German language
```

each language is having its string table maintained.
As we can use function `LoadString(ID_HERE)` to get string value from string table. I want to link different language .rc file so that I can get string for different language. By default `English.rc` file is associated with project. I want to know how I can change it to another .rc file using.

How can I load/link any particular language .rc file at runtime or can change language by selecting any language in dropdown box?
I don't want to use DLL method for it. Is there any direct method to link .rc file to project?

Comment: *"I don't want to use DLL method for it."* - I don't know what that is supposed to mean, but compiling the resource scripts into resource-only modules is the standard solution. See [Adding Multilingual User Interface Support to an Application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee845043.aspx).

Comment: @IInspectable I checked some links. in one of them it created separate DLL by adding all .rc file together and trying to use it. I think the link you provided also having something similar 'HelloModule.dll'

Comment: The tutorial I linked to creates an individual MUI module per language, plus the language-neutral *"HelloModule.dll"* file, containing both code, and language-neutral fallback resources. While it is possible to store multiple-language versions of a given resource in the same module, you'll lose the ability to use the system's MUI support, by automatically probing for language-specific MUI files. See the documentation for the [LANGUAGE statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381019.aspx) for more information.

Comment: _.rc_ files can be concatenated by simple `#include` . This produce a virtual _resources.rc_ that fits in the normal mechanism with single _.rc_ file (hello world project). But as a side effect, the texts can't be created in the visual interface any more. (because, yes, the real goal is also to simplify the translation, and having files you can compare side by side is better than a multi-language monolith).

Answer (score 1):

That's the way. You must create a resource dll and load the resources from it. Another way would be to have all resources as language depending conditions. Then, MFC would choose the resource based on the operating system language.
But it is almost impossible to keep all languages in sync for large projects and you have no control over the displayed language.

The language resource dll works sort of like this:

```
HMODULE hm = ::LoadLibrary(language_dll);
if(hm)
{
    AfxSetResourceHandle(hm);

    if(m_hLanguageDLL)
        ::FreeLibrary(m_hLanguageDLL);
    m_hLanguageDLL = hm;
}
```